# How to execute nx executor from my own executor?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

I want to run some code *after* @`nx/esbuild` complete.

So I was thinking of doing my own plugin that runs `@nx/esbuild` and then doing my own logic there.

```
export default async function echoExecutor(
  options: EchoExecutorOptions,
  context: ExecutorContext
): Promise<{ success: boolean }> {
  console.info(`Executing "echo"...`);

}
```

So I create my plugin with the executor, and I change in the `project.json` the executor from `@nx/esbuild:esbuild` to `@repo/my-plugin:echo`.

My question is how inside `runExecutor` I call `esbuild` executor? Some thing like that I expect to do:

```
import { esbuildExecutor } from '@nx/esbuild';

export default async function echoExecutor(
  options: EchoExecutorOptions,
  context: ExecutorContext
): Promise<{ success: boolean }> {
  console.info(`Executing "echo"...`);
  await esbuildExecutor(options);
  // do my own thing...
}
```